# Empty a Javascript Object (Jquery Mobile)

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, object

I have an app using jquery-mobile and jquery. 
On the first page there is an object created which is then used for temporary storage:

```
var StorageObject = new object();
```

This is defined in the global space so it is persistent in the session.
As links are clicked and actions taken the object is updated with values:

```
StorageObject.value = 'something';
```

My problem is where you need to empty the object (if someone clicks cancel or something) and start again requiring an empty storage object. Because jquery-mobile is essentially all on one page there is no reloading of the global space and therefore the storage object persists from last use.
I do not believe there is anything I can call to empty the object without writing some recursive code to run through every value and empty it.

Is there a way of emptying the object or should I be doing this another way?

===========================================

Edit:

Having followed the advice of those below I still had the problem of an array within the storage object. 
I have to change the initial definition so i defined the storage object from:

```
StorageObject.value  = 0;
StorageObject.ArrayofValues = new Array();
```

to:

```
function MyStorageObject(){
  this.value = 0;
  this.ArrayofValues = new Array();
};

var StorageObject = new MyStorageObject();
```

from there on in I can, as others have suggested, just call:

```
StorageObject = new MyStorageObject();
```

to get a new copy of it :)

Comment: How many references to the object do you have? If `StorageObject` is the only reference just say `StorageObject = {}` or `StorageObject = new Object();` and the old object will be garbage collected.

Comment: As there is probably no direct reference to the object, you should simply be able to do `StorageObject = new object();` to have a new one, no ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If really needed, you can [loop over](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) and [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) each property:

```
for (var prop in StorageObject) {
    if (StorageObject.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        delete StorageObject[prop];
    }
}
```

Otherwise, as others have suggested, just replace it with a different `Object`:

```
StorageObject = {};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't empty the object itself, you have to empty it manually, maybe using a custom function like this:

```
StorageObject.empty = function(){
    //empty all my data
}
```

or, if you need just to refer to the StorageObject variabile, you can just set it to null or to a new object instance every time you need to reset it like this

```
StorageObject = null;
```

or this

```
StorageObject = new Object();
```